# Using CSS to create a dynamically reordering grid of icons?

Tags: css, html, alignment

Note: Script is not an option for me

I am sending emails to customers with a set of 12 100X100 icons like this at the bottom of the email (100% width, evenly spaced):

```
X X X X X X
X X X X X X
```

If they open the email on a smaller width device it should reorder:

```
x x x x 
x x x x
x x x x
```

and

```
X X X 
X X X 
X X X
X X X
```

etc

Is this possible in CSS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `display:inline-block;`.

Your divs will be block elements but you will be able to manipulate them like any other inline element. You can even justify them to fill the enter width of the container.

**Example**

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/woestijnrog/gzXxG/6/)

Answer (score 4):

Yes, using floating elements. By floating elements to the left they will break to the next line when they reach the right edge. Use a `div` element as container, as it by default has the width `auto`, which uses all the available width. Example:

HTML:

```
<div class="Container">
  <div class="item">X</div>
  <div class="item">X</div>
  <div class="item">X</div>
  <div class="item">X</div>
  <div class="item">X</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.Container { overflow: hidden; }
.Container .item { float: left; width: 100px; height: 100px; }
```

Setting the `overflow` style on the container without specifying any width or height, will make the child elements stay inside the container. Without it, the child element would not affect the height of the container, so it would get the height zero.

Comment: I was going to post an answer similar to this, but I realized it would not work on email clients such as Outlook 2007, 2010.

Comment: Floats really aren't the way to do this with email- please see campaign monitor's "will it work" guidelines: http://www.campaignmonitor.com/resources/will-it-work/guidelines/#use_tables

Answer (score 1):

If your using just a single div and a bunch of anchor image tags, then just set the `max-width` property.

**HTML:**

```html
<div class="icons">
    <a href="#"><img src="image1.png" /></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="image2.png" /></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="image3.png" /></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="image4.png" /></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="image5.png" /></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="image6.png" /></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="image7.png" /></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="image8.png" /></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="image9.png" /></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="image10.png" /></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="image11.png" /></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="image12.png" /></a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```css
.icons {
    max-width: 600px;
}
```

DEMO:

[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/FMXSB/)